# Need one div's input value to switch from true to false onclick and then revert onclick of another div

Tags: jquery

I have these buttons...which use the jQuery knobs by Anthony Terrien
http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

These buttons have jQuery functions which Ive added and are already working which toggle certain styles (display this box shadow /don't display it, etc.)

However I now need to hide/display a value of an input field

When one div is clicked the input val "data-displayInput" should be false, When a DIFFERENT one of these buttons is clicked (not the same one) it should return to true, and the next one should be false.

I tried the following:

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  var hiddenField = $('#data-displayInput'),
      val = hiddenField.val();

  hiddenField.val(val === "true" ? "false" : "true");
  console.log("new value: " + hiddenField.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"><input class="knob" value="80" data-displayInput="true"/></div>
    <div id="button"><input class="knob" value="60" data-displayInput="true"/></div>
    <div id="button"><input class="knob" value="40" data-displayInput="true"/></div>
    <div id="button"><input class="knob" value="20" data-displayInput="true"/></div>
```

Just not really sure what I'm missing.
Note it has to be a click on the button and NOT on the Input itself.

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple DIVs with `id="button"`. Use a class instead.

Comment: `$('#data-displayInput')` looks for an element with `id="data-displayInput"`. Where do you have that?

Comment: Yes, I meant to put class. the divs all have a class of button.

Comment: Barmar, I do not have such an id, would I need to use 'data-displayInput' instead?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (Assuming you switch your ID to a class)

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(".button").attr("data-displayInput", "false");
  $(this).attr("data-displayInput", "true");
}
```

This switches all other elements with this class to false, then switches the clicked one to true. You can even add classes to the elements with only the purpse of labeling them incase you can multiple sets of elements. `$(".button.buttonset01")`

Answer (score 0):

Change `id="button"` to `class="button"`, since IDs have to be unique. To access the value of the `data-displayInput` attribute, use `.attr()`; `$("#data-displayInput")` selects an element whose ID is `data-displayInput`, and `.val()` is for accessing the value of a user input element.

And since the attribute is on the `<input>` element, not the `<div>`, you have to use `.find()` to get to it.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $(".knob").attr('data-displayInput', 'true'); // Set others to true
  $(this).find('.knob').attr('data-displayInput', 'false'); // Set this one false
});
```

```css
.knob[data-displayInput=true] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.knob[data-displayInput=false] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <input class="knob" value="80" data-displayInput="true" />
</div>
<div class="button">
  <input class="knob" value="60" data-displayInput="true" />
</div>
<div class="button">
  <input class="knob" value="40" data-displayInput="true" />
</div>
<div class="button">
  <input class="knob" value="20" data-displayInput="true" />
</div>
```

Comment: Barmar, and @Grallen, I tried this code (Barmar's above) and if I remove the knob.js link, it does work. Something in knob messes it up. I added a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/rubixkube/rfca1yfa/

Comment: I think the plugin only looks at the `data-X` attributes when you first initialize it. Plugins don't react to DOM changes automatically like the browser does. You should check the documentation of the plugin to see if there's an API to change the attributes on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

So, with the help of the above answers and a friend, I learned a lot today.  But I basically just changed the code to this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    $(".knob").css("display", ""); // Set others to true
    $(this).find('.knob').css("display", "none"); // Set this one false
});
```

you can see the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/rubixkube/rfca1yfa/2/